# Checking whether a string is a permutation of a palindrome in C++20

Tags: c++, palindrome, c++20

(See the next iteration/follow-up [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272256/checking-whether-a-string-is-a-permutation-of-a-palindrome-in-c20-follow-up).)

I have this short function `is_permutation_palindrome`, which returns `true` only if the input string may be rearranged to form a palindrome:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

bool is_permutation_palindrome(const std::string& text)
{
    std::unordered_map<char, size_t> counter_map;

    for (const auto ch : text)
        ++counter_map[ch];

    size_t number_of_odd_chars = 0;

    for (const auto &pair: counter_map)
        if (counter_map[pair.first] % 2 == 1)
        {
            ++number_of_odd_chars;

            if (number_of_odd_chars > 1)
                return false;
        }

    return true;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << is_permutation_palindrome("yash") << "\n";
    std::cout << is_permutation_palindrome("vcciv") << "\n";
    std::cout << is_permutation_palindrome("abnnab") << "\n";   
}
```

**Critique request**

I believe that there must be a more idiomatic way of implementing that function, and would like to hear about it.

Comment: What is the encoding of the input string? I would assume ASCII, given the use of `char` doesn't deal with any Unicode flavor correctly, but it'd be great to have that specified.

Comment: @MatthieuM. it doesn't matter what the encoding is, as long as it consists of single-byte characters.

Comment: @JDługosz: The "as long as" is a fairly important restriction though, UCS-2, UTF-16, UTF-32, Shift-JIS, etc... all fail here. Although I was asking more with an eye to optimization: ASCII only requires 7 bits, not 8, which reduces the size of arrays/bitsets.

Comment: @MatthieuM - UCS-2 should be fine, as well as UTF-32 (which is exactly equal to UCS-4), for platforms that support one of those as `char`.  It's only the encodings where multiple `char` are needed to represent a single code-point that fail (and even then, only as false-positives, never as false-negatives).

Comment: @TobySpeight: You are theoretically correct, however in practice the mainstream platforms don't support them as `char` that I know of...

Comment: @TobySpeight still no good with 32-bit characters, because the algorithm would be operating on _code points_ not complete characters, which can consist of a base plus multiple combining characters.  Using a "precomposed" normalized form will work _if_ all needed characters have precomposed code points.

Comment: I was just responding to the comment about single-byte encodings.  You're right that there is still a distinction between a code-point and a character.  And then we need to ask how we define a palindrome (traditionally, the definition ignores spaces, punctuation and accents in English; I'm not sure about other languages).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While your algorithm is \$O(n)\$, the constant factors are considerable. Specifically, you are suffering due to all the nodes the map needs.

Better options are:

1. Just `std::sort()` and then do a single pass. While the order is \$O(n * log(n))\$, it will probably still be far more efficient.
2. Use an array for a histogram. 256 elements (wrap-around of an unsigned type would be safe, so `unsigned char` suffices, or even flipping a `bool`) should fit comfortably.
   Even if you are on a rare platform with bigger bytes, it ought to fit or you have bigger problems with your current implementation.
   While the order is the same, the constants are far smaller.

Regarding your implementation:

1. Unless you need a null-terminated read-only string, passing by `std::string const&` is very sub-optimal. Considering your chosen algorithm, `std::string_view` would be best.
2. You could mark your algorithm `constexpr`.
   `noexcept` unfortunately eludes you due to all the allocations.

```
constexpr bool is_permutation_palindrome(std::string_view s) noexcept {
    unsigned char counts[1u + (unsigned char)-1] {};
    for (unsigned char c : s)
        ++counts[c];
    return std::ranges::count_if(counts, [](auto a){ return a % 2; }) < 2;
}
```

Comment: Option 2 is only valid if you define permutation as being of *bytes* rather than of *characters*.

Comment: If unsigned char wouldn't have overflow behavior this would break or if the result wouldn't be depending on value being even (if it would be divisibility by 3 for example it would break due to overflow).

Comment: @Incomputable Technically, unsigned types cannot overflow in C or C++, as operations are defined to wrap around, which as you said is fine here. Only signed types can overflow.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE If you allow for multi-byte characters (like unicode codepoints) or even graphemes, things get far more involved, true. But that's beyond the scope of the question, imho.

Answer (score 8):

Using a `std::unordered_map` is overkill here, since the number of possible characters is known beforehand. So you could just use a `std::array<std::size_t, 256>`. But you can do even better than that: you don't need to know the exact number of occurences of a given character, you only need to know if it's odd or even. You just need one bit to keep track of that. So consider using a [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). The solution then becomes:

```
bool is_permutation_palindrome(const std::string& text)
{
    std::bitset<256> odd_characters;

    for (const auto ch : text)
        odd_characters.flip(static_cast<std::uint8_t>(ch));

    return odd_characters.count() <= 1;
}
```

Note that the above assumes 8 bits in a `char`, which might not be completely portable. You might want to check the value of [`CHAR_BIT`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits).

Comment: I wonder whether compressing so much helps or hinders more. byte-granularity access is more natural...

Comment: It depends on the CPU architecture. A benchmark would be able to prove which algorithm is best for a given set of inputs.

Comment: For other size chars, I think it's sufficient to have `std::bitset<UCHAR_MAX>` (and change the cast, to `unsigned char`).  I don't see any need to use `CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: @TobySpeight `UCHAR_MAX` is the maximum value, not the number of values. Still, I prefer avoiding all macros, as there is no true need to use one.

Comment: I don't think there is *any* mainstream CPU architecture that can access individual bits as quickly as it can access bytes. The compiler is going to generate bit-shifting and -making instructions implicitly. Certainly, that is not true of either x86 or ARM. A byte-array will therefore give you vastly more efficient performance than trying to pack everything into a bit-field. Of course, memory usage will be higher, but that's generally not an issue (classic trade-off), and *definitely* not in this case where you are only talking about a maximum size of 256 bytes (versus 256 bits == 32 bytes).

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not saying this is the fastest way, you definitely should benchmark it. But even x86 has instructions for [setting individual bits](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bts), and besides that, consider that a lot of processors nowadays have 256 bit registers (think AVX) so you can avoid any memory access (since even L1 cache has some latency, and 256 bytes is still more than one cache line).

Comment: +1 for noticing that only parity is necessary. For a larger space, it may be interesting to keep a counter of odd values as you go, to avoid the O(space-size) count at the end, but for 128 or 256 bits, simplifying the inner-loop as you did is probably better.

Comment: @G.Sliepen, I believe AVX will not help here since it is updating multiple locations instead of writing in one place. Sure it would help with the summation, but actual histogram calculation is not AVX-able, as far as I know.

Comment: @G.Sliepen memory-destination `bts` / `btc` / `btr` with a runtime-variable index like `btc [rdi], eax` is slower (about 10 uops on Skylake with one per 5 cycle throughput even on independent memory locations, https://uops.info/html-instr/BTS_M32_R32.html) than manually splitting the bit-index into byte address and bit-within-byte for a `movzx` load / reg-reg `btc edx, eax` / byte store.  For very short input strings, lower cost to zero and check the count array is worth it, but for longer you want to overlap more increments (out-of-order exec); fewer uops fills up the out-of-order window less

Comment: @G.Sliepen AVX2 is pretty hard to use for this; it might allow you to shorten the critical path latency down to just a `vpxor` instruction, but it would take multiple instructions to materialize the `1<<n` vector (perhaps `xor edx,edx` / `bts rdx, rax` / `vmovq xmm0, rdx` to materialize a `1<<(n&63)`, then a shuffle like `vpermq` with a lookup table of shuffle control vectors indexed by the higher bits of `n`?  Anyway, this puts *every* update on the same critical path, instead of taking advantage of the memory-level parallelism of separate bytes in L1d cache, which is only bad for repeats.

Comment: G.Sliepen, in summary @CodyGray is right: for long strings on modern x86, your best bet is a loop like `movzx eax, byte [rdi]` (get a char, 1 uop) / `xor byte [table + rax], 1` (flip a bool, 2 uops micro-fused on Intel) / `inc rdi` (ptr++) / `cmp rdi, rsi + jnz .loop` `do{}while(p != endp)`.  Then you use AVX2 to PADDB together 8 vectors (256 bytes) of counters, then `vpsadbw` against zero and so on to horizontal sum, eventually checking that the non-overflowing (widened) sum of all 256 bytes is <= 1.  Maybe something with `vpcmpgtd` against 0 and 1 and `vmovmskps` -> `popcnt` instead of hsum?

Comment: (If the std::bitset version uses 64-bit chunks and loads/stores after each bit-flip, any bit in the same group of 64 is part of the same dep chain, so alphabetic input would be just in two 64-bit chunks, upper and lower, so data dependency bottlenecks are a very real possibility for the bitset.)  Yup, both GCC with libstdc++ and clang libc++ make that unfortunate choice: https://godbolt.org/z/jazadTh8q.  Notice the `xor     QWORD PTR [rsp-32+rax*8], rdx` or clang's `mov` from/to `qword ptr [rsp + rdx]`.  (And clang's hilarious bts / btr / bt / cmovc emulation of btc complement)

Comment: @PeterCordes Nice analysis. I'm shocked by the assembly produced by both OP's and my version. Deduplicator's version looks better, and it's indeed not surprising it performs better in Incomputable's benchmarks.

Comment: @Deduplicator, if you're allergic to macros, you _could_ replace `UCHAR_MAX` with `std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()` (and add one, of course - sorry for that oversight).  But I find that a bit of a mouthful, and prefer the macro here.  The long form can be very useful in generic code.

Answer (score 5):

### Code Review

I have some small nitpicks, but otherwise looks good.

**Use string_view**

As Deduplicator mentioned, it is better to clarify that the function does not expect exactly `std::string`, but just a continuous sequence of `char`s with a size.

**Structured binding**

Although in this case the map is not useful, it would be better to name the `.first` and `.second` variables:

```cpp
    for (const auto& [value, occurence_count]: counter_map)
```

**Misspelling std::size_t**

This is even more minor one, but perhaps with advent of modules this might change.

### Consumption

Although this is not intended to be consumed by somebody as a library, it would be great to write basic CMakeLists file to specify build requirements.

### Benchmarks

Without too much talking, I will dump my benchmark code (there are some slight modifications):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>
#include <memory_resource>

#include "input_gen.h"

// Based on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/272128
// from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/58360/coderodde
bool is_permutation_palindrome_original(const std::string& text)
{
    const std::size_t buffer_size = 8 * 1024;
    std::array<std::byte, buffer_size> scratch;
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource resource(scratch.data(), buffer_size);
    std::pmr::unordered_map<char, size_t> counter_map(&resource);
//    counter_map.reserve(256);

    for (const auto ch : text)
        ++counter_map[ch];

    size_t number_of_odd_chars = 0;

    for (const auto &pair: counter_map)
        if (counter_map[pair.first] % 2 == 1)
        {
            ++number_of_odd_chars;

            if (number_of_odd_chars > 1)
                return false;
        }

    return true;
}

// based on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/272130
// from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42409/deduplicator
bool is_permutation_palindrome_array(std::string_view s) noexcept {
    unsigned char counts[1u + std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()] {};
    for (unsigned char c : s)
        ++counts[c];
    return std::count_if(std::begin(counts), std::end(counts), [](auto a){ return a % 2; }) < 2;
}

// https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/272129
// from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/129343/g-sliepen
bool is_permutation_palindrome_bitset(const std::string& text)
{
    std::bitset<256> odd_characters;

    for (const auto ch : text)
        odd_characters.flip(static_cast<std::uint8_t>(ch));

    return odd_characters.count() <= 1;
}

#include <chrono>
namespace chrono = std::chrono;

struct sample_t {
    chrono::nanoseconds original_time;
    chrono::nanoseconds array_time;
    chrono::nanoseconds bitset_time;
};

sample_t measure(const std::string& input) {
    sample_t sample{};
    {
        auto start_time = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        volatile bool is_pal = is_permutation_palindrome_original(input);
        auto end_time = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        sample.original_time = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end_time - start_time);
    }


    {
        auto start_time = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        volatile bool is_pal = is_permutation_palindrome_array(input);
        auto end_time = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        sample.array_time = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end_time - start_time);
    }

    {
        auto start_time = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        volatile bool is_pal = is_permutation_palindrome_bitset(input);
        auto end_time = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        sample.bitset_time = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end_time - start_time);
    }

    return sample;
}

struct metric_t {
    chrono::nanoseconds min = chrono::nanoseconds(std::numeric_limits<std::int64_t>::max());
    chrono::nanoseconds max = chrono::nanoseconds(0);
    chrono::nanoseconds sum = chrono::nanoseconds(0);

    void update(chrono::nanoseconds new_sample) {
        if (min > new_sample) {
            min = new_sample;
        }

        if (max < new_sample) {
            max = new_sample;
        }

        sum += new_sample;
    }
};


#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 4) {
        std::cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " <input-size> <run-count> <output-file>\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    const std::size_t size = std::stoull(argv[1]);
    const std::size_t target_amount_of_runs = std::stoull(argv[2]);

    std::vector<sample_t> samples;
    samples.reserve(target_amount_of_runs);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < target_amount_of_runs; ++i) {
        auto input = shino::generate_random_input(size);
        auto sample = measure(input);
        samples.push_back(sample);
    }

    metric_t metrics_for_og;
    metric_t metrics_for_array;
    metric_t metrics_for_bitset;
    for (const auto& sample: samples) {
        metrics_for_og.update(sample.original_time);
        metrics_for_array.update(sample.array_time);
        metrics_for_bitset.update(sample.bitset_time);
    }

    chrono::nanoseconds avg_time_og = metrics_for_og.sum / target_amount_of_runs;
    chrono::nanoseconds avg_time_array = metrics_for_array.sum / target_amount_of_runs;
    chrono::nanoseconds avg_time_bitset = metrics_for_bitset.sum / target_amount_of_runs;

    std::vector<chrono::nanoseconds> og_samples;
    og_samples.reserve(target_amount_of_runs);
    std::vector<chrono::nanoseconds> array_samples;
    array_samples.reserve(target_amount_of_runs);
    std::vector<chrono::nanoseconds> bitset_samples;
    bitset_samples.reserve(target_amount_of_runs);
    for (const auto& sample: samples) {
        og_samples.push_back(sample.original_time);
        array_samples.push_back(sample.array_time);
        bitset_samples.push_back(sample.bitset_time);
    }

    std::sort(og_samples.begin(), og_samples.end());
    std::sort(array_samples.begin(), array_samples.end());
    std::sort(bitset_samples.begin(), bitset_samples.end());

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "original function metrics (ns):\n"
        << "\tmin: " << metrics_for_og.min.count() << '\n'
        << "\tmax: " << metrics_for_og.max.count() << '\n'
        << "\tavg: " << avg_time_og.count() << '\n'
        << "\t98th percentile: " << og_samples[target_amount_of_runs * 0.98].count()
              << "\n\n";

    oss << "array based function metrics (ns):\n"
        << "\tmin: " << metrics_for_array.min.count() << '\n'
        << "\tmax: " << metrics_for_array.max.count() << '\n'
        << "\tavg: " << avg_time_array.count() << '\n'
        << "\t98th percentile: " << array_samples[target_amount_of_runs * 0.98].count()
              << "\n\n";

    oss << "bitset based function metrics (ns):\n"
        << "\tmin: " << metrics_for_bitset.min.count() << '\n'
        << "\tmax: " << metrics_for_bitset.max.count() << '\n'
        << "\tavg: " << avg_time_bitset.count() << '\n'
        << "\t98th percentile: " << bitset_samples[target_amount_of_runs * 0.98].count()
              << "\n\n";

    std::ofstream output_file(argv[3]);
    if (!output_file) {
        std::cerr << "opening output file failed, printing results to stderr:\n"
                  << oss.str();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    output_file << oss.str();
}
```

And `input_gen.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef IS_PAL_INPUT_GEN_H
#define IS_PAL_INPUT_GEN_H

#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

namespace shino {

// the input is under 1MiB
// only request at a time
inline std::string generate_random_input(std::size_t size) {
    std::minstd_rand0 generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<char> dist;
    std::string result(size, '\0');
    std::generate(result.begin(), result.end(),
                  [&dist, &generator]() {
        return dist(generator);
    });

    return result;
}

}

#endif //IS_PAL_INPUT_GEN_H
```

Alright, with that out of the way, here is how and why I benchmarked the code:

**Benchmark metric**: I used latency as the metric. Of course I also got OS scheduling, I/O interrupts and other stuff in there, but I also did 98th percentile test to see if the deviation is too big. All of the three versions I benchmarked were pretty close to average on 98th percentile, albeit being slower than average sample.

**Sampling**: I decided to do the basic run and measure, using `std::chrono::steady_clock`, because both `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` and system version failed me once (They readjusted to invalidate my results). I did not use any benchmarking library because they don't really measure latency, but throughput.

**Metrics list**:

- Fastest sample
- Slowest sample
- Average sample
- 98th percentile sample

### Results:

The benchmark was run with input size 1024 and run count 1048576.

I'm gonna separate the answers' versions from the changes I made, so here are the results from Deduplicator and G. Sliepen:

```
array based function metrics (ns):
        min: 402
        max: 30785
        avg: 418
        98th percentile: 460

bitset based function metrics (ns):
        min: 705
        max: 41427
        avg: 768
        98th percentile: 916
```

Verbatim version (perhaps there are small changes, I do not remember correctly):

```
original function metrics (ns):
        min: 4055
        max: 83646
        avg: 4169
        98th percentile: 4303
```

Reserve:

```
original function metrics (ns):
        min: 4350
        max: 69625
        avg: 4546
        98th percentile: 4678
```

**Reserve seems to give negative effect**.

PMR version with no reserve:

```
original function metrics (ns):
        min: 4814
        max: 91582
        avg: 5129
        98th percentile: 5539
```

**PMR version seems to be slower**.

The original version of PMR, with oversized buffer on the stack:

```
original function metrics (ns):
        min: 5111
        max: 582302
        avg: 5345
        98th percentile: 5489
```

**Even worse**.

PMR with 8kb buffer and reserve:

```
        min: 5160
        max: 74025
        avg: 5416
        98th percentile: 5572
```

**Even more worse**.

---

I have no idea why anything I do with `std::unordered_map` makes it perform worse. It is clear that the array based version is faster, a lot faster than map version and considerably faster than bitset version.

I also managed to stumble upon the functions being optimized out, but volatile solved that problem.

---

Repo: https://github.com/simmplecoder/is-palindrome-benchmark

---

Specific updates: array vs bitset.

I separated input generation into three functions:

```cpp
inline std::string generate_homogenous_input(std::size_t size) {
    std::string result(size, '\0');
    std::fill(result.begin(), result.end(), 'a');
    return result;
}

inline std::string generate_spread_input(std::size_t size) {
    std::string result(size, '\0');

    unsigned char start_char = 0;
    for (auto& c: result) {
        c = static_cast<char>(start_char);
        start_char += sizeof(std::size_t) * CHAR_BIT;
    }

    return result;
}

// the input is under 1MiB
// only request at a time
inline std::string generate_random_input(std::size_t size) {
    std::minstd_rand0 generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<char> dist;
    std::string result(size, '\0');
    std::generate(result.begin(), result.end(),
                  [&dist, &generator]() {
                      return dist(generator);
                  });

    return result;
}
```

This is in response to [@PeterCordes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/50567/peter-cordes) about performance of bitset when there is a data dependency (the next iteration flip bit from the same word as the current).

I guess I fixed something and now the average is actually above 98th percentile, which is correct. It means that more often than not the benchmarks stayed in the same range. Here are the results:

input size: 1024, run count: 1048576 homogenous input (all 'a's)

array version:

```
metrics for array based version(ns):
        min time: 1330
        max time: 11382
        avg time: 3033
        98th percentile time: 1750
```

bitset version:

```
metrics for bitset based version:
        min time: 1248
        max time: 27424
        avg time: 2826
        98th percentile time: 1761
```

It can be seen that Peter was correct. When there is a dependency on the previous iteration, the execution pipeline will stall. It can seen in `perf` with very high backend stall.

input size: 1024, run count: 1048576, input generation type: spread (64 values)

Array version:

```
metrics for array based version(ns):
        min time: 405
        max time: 14208
        avg time: 859
        98th percentile time: 525
```

Bitset version:

```
metrics for bitset based version:
        min time: 515
        max time: 9464
        avg time: 1161
        98th percentile time: 617
```

This is the best case scenario for each version because now they do not have dependency. The only problem with bitset is that it probably compiles down to more instructions.

input size: 1024, run count: 1048576, input generation type: random

The values did not change for this one (as they should) and they are written above.

---

Runtime environment (gaming rig):

CPU: intel i7 11700k, no overclocking

RAM: 3200MHz, don't remember the timings.

OS: Ubuntu 21.10

g++: 11.2.0

No demanding software was active, but then this is not RTOS, it will be far from perfect anyway.

---

I recorded some videos with the process. The [first one](https://youtu.be/JpbmOLYv9KQ) turned out quite horrible. The [next part](https://youtu.be/9usa5psxdq0) I believe got quite better because it got more focus and less of me making basic errors. The [last part](https://youtu.be/pDFqFnDV7V0) is just a comparison with some analysis (and confusion).

Comment: I also did a video with entirety of the process (and me endlessly stumbling on basic mistakes xD ) but YouTube is very slow on the processing side. Please comment if you would like to watch it, it is more than an hour long and honestly boring, but it does show the methodology in its entirety, which I believe is important.

Comment: Nice testing. I assume it was on a barely loaded modern desktop, but I would have expected it spelled out.

Comment: @Deduplicator, nice catch. The hardware specs are in the video, but I've forgotten to include it here. Fixed.

Comment: You said you're testing latency, but the `bool` result of one run isn't an input to the next run.  And `chrono::steady_clock::now()` doesn't necessarily drain the ROB for out-of-order execution.  So you're not blocking out-of-order exec between runs, or making one of them data-dependent on the previous.  That's basically throughput, or at least how well each run can overlap execution with the code of `chrono::steady_clock::now()`.

Comment: BTW, fully random `char` data is very very good for the array and bitset based versions; runs of repeats are very unlikely so they won't encounter long store-forwarding dependency chains.  (If the bitset version uses 64-bit chunks and loads/stores after each bit-flip, any bit in the same group of 64 is part of the same dep chain, so alphabetic input would be just in two 64-bit chunks, upper and lower, so data dependency bottlenecks are a very real possibility for the bitset.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, fair point. I will test that tomorrow and update. I was thinking about memory barriers, but did not know about full effects. Overall I think I’m going to redo this. Doing it live on recording scrambled my thoughts drastically.

Comment: @PeterCordes on the side note, do you know what is going on with the map? Whatever I did just made it worse. Is there any libstdc++ bug report related to this?

Comment: No, IDK about `std::unordered_map` performance details.  Although 256 elements is probably too small for good performance; with 256 unique char values possible, you'd get hash collisions.  And 8k is probably too larger.  Maybe 512, for a 50% load factor on the hash table?  Or no, I think [Why does std::unordered\_map have a reserve method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42373232) is saying that `reserve` should take into account the load factor and reserve enough buckets to hold `n` elements (with that comfortable load factor?)

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could try to figure out the underlying ABI and fine tune the memory resource. 8k is about bytes, I wanted to be careful to not overwrite my stack in case I did not allocate enough.

Comment: Very nice benchmarks. I would like to see the YouTube video! I wonder what the performance would be if the second pass over the counters would be removed, and instead we keep track of the number of odd counters during the first pass. That might make a big difference for small strings.

Comment: What is the input size you used for your benchmark results? I noticed that for small inputs, bitset wins. But the size where array starts being faster depends on the CPU; on a AMD Ryzen 3900X, bitset wins up to size 256, on an Apple M1, bitset wins up to size 32.

Comment: I think that `UCHAR_MAX` would be clearer to the reader than `(unsigned char)-1`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen, I put the run count and input size values, sorry for forgetting those! By the way, check out the updates. The processing on the video finally completed for FullHD: https://youtu.be/JpbmOLYv9KQ . I also did another round of videos on what Peter suggested, here is part 1 but it is far from being processed: https://youtu.be/9usa5psxdq0 . The latter ones are better in quality from my POV. They are more concise and have less of me messing up my own code :)

Comment: @PeterCordes, I did an update with your suggestions. Interestingly, `perf` showed about the same backend stall for both array and bitset version with random input. I did not check the distribution of what `mindstd_rand` generated, here is the video if you would like to check what is going on (not finished processing on youtube yet): https://youtu.be/9usa5psxdq0

Comment: @TobySpeight, I changed it to numeric limits, thanks! I hope I changed all instances, the post is getting a bit out of hand.

Comment: Yeah, `array` will stall, too, if you have the exact same character repeating.  But if you have random within a..z, that's still worst-case for bitset, but plenty of memory-level parallelism for array, so you'll see a bigger speed difference.  Even just alternating ababab would make `array` about twice as fast with 2 memory dep chains.  Re: same back-end stall: yeah, with a large latency bottleneck, that gives the extra instructions for bitset indexing time to execute and still stall waiting for store/reload store-forwarding.  There aren't *that* many more, so it's relatively close.

Comment: The key point here is that many real-world use cases are likely to include a lot of alphabetic characters, so having that be best-case for one vs. worst-case for the other is not unlikely.  (And BTW, out-of-order exec can hide small runs like `aaabbbaaabbb`.)  One solution to the dep-chain problem with histograms is unrolling over multiple count arrays, which could be useful if we expect large inputs with long runs (e.g. sorted), otherwise it's more overhead.  As in [this Q&A on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12985949).

Comment: @PeterCordes, that trick looks like basic thread local storage + combining at the end. Also, I believe perf also measures `std::minstd_rand`, so my explanation is that it has higher percentage of stalls because of that and in reality the performance difference is much larger. It is only a theory though.

Comment: Yeah, thread-local storage and combining at the end is the thread-level equivalent of having multiple dependency chains within one thread for instruction-level-parallelism.  ([Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45113527) / [What considerations go into predicting latency for operations on modern superscalar processors and how can I calculate them by hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51607391)).  And yeah, `perf stat` on the whole process includes init/rng work.

Comment: There's a follow question to this, with a template that can accept wider char type.  In that case, we can still get the benefit of `array<std::uint_fast8_t, 256>` for 8-bit types on normal systems, using `std::conditional`: I posted an answer on [Checking whether a string is a permutation of a palindrome in C++20 - follow-up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/272272) but didn't get around to actually looking at the asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes I checked it out. I guess performance characteristics will not change much with type if a map is used consistently? I've got into gstreamer plugin development (well, I am trying to comprehend it). I was thinking about writing a gstreamer pipeline with histogram computation on the fly. It will take a while though.

Comment: Yeah, I'd expect `std::unordered_map` to be as slow for `wchar_t` as for `char`, but an array is no longer a good option in that case so there's no speed to gain. Unless you want to optimistically start with an array in case it happens to be UTF-16 or UTF-32 holding plain ASCII chars, with a bail-out conversion to a hash table on seeing a high value. (You can easily OR the first up-to-8 32-bit elements down to 4 with SIMD, and check that none of them are > 128.  `por` / `pcmpgtd` / `pmovmskb` / test/jnz to jump if any of the first 8 elements *are* outside the range of an array before starting)

Comment: @PeterCordes, I believe the best idea in situations with large types is to somehow code it (usually inputs are small so they don't saturate the entire value space). I believe most of the time histograms will be sparse so encoding it, doing histogram and decoding it would probably allow using arrays.

Comment: (see edit to previous comment).  Hmm, interesting idea.  Yeah, if have have a perfect "hash" function that can map any of the expected set of inputs into a small range, and produce a detectable value for inputs where that's not possible, you could use a std::array as a hand-rolled hash table.  Otherwise, std::unordered_map's hash function can map it to an array with collision detection and a fallback to whatever strategy it uses, and checks to maybe grow the hash table...

Answer (score 3):

The other comments so far assume 8-bit characters.  If this is not the case, you would want to convert your multi-byte string to `char32_t`, normalize (for example, by converting all characters to canonical NFD form and discarding all combining characters, counting only the base characters) and then keeping a count of each characters in a `std::unordered_map` with `char32_t` as the key type and `size_t` as the value type.  To increment the count, you would extract the key in constant time, increment the count or create a new key-value pair if it is not present, then insert it with an incremented count.

Unfortunately, you need `char32_t` because Windows uses 16-bit `wchar_t`, which does not conform to the language Standard, because of surrogate pairs.  (The original sin of Unicode was thinking that 16 bits would be enough.  When the C language committee decreed that `wchar_t` must be a fixed-width encoding, Microsoft said, no, they were not breaking the entire Windows API.)  A hashed canonical representation of a multi-byte substring could work too.

An implementation that conforms to the C++ language standard must also honor the canonical equivalence of different representations.  In most languages, you would want to canonically decompose and ignore accents, but if you want to recognize only characters with the same accents as palindromes, you would need to canonically compose them instead, and possibly even use hashed strings as your keys.  You probably also want to ignore all non-alphanumeric characters, and normalize all characters to the same case, to recognize “Madam in Eden, I’m Adam,” as a palindrome.

In short, the C++ Standard Library does not have the features you would need to do this correctly in Unicode, and you would need a third-party library such as ICU.

G. Sleipen is, however, correct that you merely need to check that there is at most one character with an odd-numbered count.

Comment: Going full unicode or at least catering to mbcs is interesting, especially deciding to throw away combining characters changes things. BTW: My answer doesn't assume minimal size bytes anywhere, though I do mention that the table could become infeasibly large if a byte is too big.

Comment: @Deduplicator I think an `unordered_map` on `char32_t` as the key type (or a hashed canonical representation of a multi-byte string could work too), with a count as the value type, would be the way to go.